# MS Access syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query and I have no idea why I am getting the error `Syntax error in FROM clause`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_object 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM t_objectproperties tag 
   WHERE tag.Property = 'Location' 
     AND tag.Value = 'Queens'
) AS location 
   ON t_object.Object_ID = location.Object_ID 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM t_objectproperties tag 
   WHERE tag.Property = 'Room' 
     AND tag.Value = 'King'
) AS type 
   ON t_object.Object_ID = type.Object_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access requires that you use parentheses around your multiple joins:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (t_object 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM t_objectproperties as tag 
   WHERE tag.Property = 'Location' 
     AND tag.Value = 'Queens'
) AS location 
   ON t_object.Object_ID = location.Object_ID) 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM t_objectproperties as tag 
   WHERE tag.Property = 'Room' 
     AND tag.Value = 'King'
) AS type 
   ON t_object.Object_ID = type.Object_ID
```

This could also be rewritten as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (t_object as o
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location 
         ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
         ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID
WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
  AND location.Value = 'Queens'
  AND type.Property = 'Room' 
  AND type.Value = 'King'
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. I tried that but I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. Now I get the error `Syntax error in JOIN operation`

Comment: Not `FROM t_objectproperties tag`.  Rather `FROM t_objectproperties AS tag`.  It's a Access thing.

Comment: @Smandoli yup, you're right. It's been a while for me in Access

Comment: @bluefeet -  Thanks bluefeet. That worked like a charm however is returning duplicates of some records even though there is a single record.

Comment: @bluefeet - Does it mean that `t_object o` would be `t_object AS o`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey yes you will have to use `t_objects as o`, as far as the duplicates it is difficult to say why without seeing your table structures/sample data.  A possible solution would be to use `distinct`, but I can't say for sure without seeing more details.

Comment: @bluefeet - Thanks @bluefeet. How would I use `distinct` in the query you provided? Secondly is there another way to write the query because although it returns the results, the application I am using that queries the database doesn't permit me to select the record. It could be an issue with the application however if I simplify the query to a simple `SELECT`, it allows me to select and edit the query.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey you would use `select distinct *` if you need to return distinct rows, but as far as your another question - you will have to ask a new one and provide those details.

Comment: @bluefeet - Thanks bluefeet. I did try using `DISTINCT` however I get the error `Can't include Memo or OLE Object when you select unique values`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey There are certain datatypes that cannot use distinct including `memo`. As I said without further details, I can't assist but if you have more questions I would post a new question with those requirements.

Comment: @bluefeet - Really appreciate your help.