# Is SQL written for SQLite interchangeable with SQL for an Access database?

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access-2010

I have written a project in C# which currently uses a SQLite database with 7 tables. Now I made a little mistake in selecting my database and since the application is going to be accessed by multiple users (~100) on a network the SQLite solution won't work because only one user can write at a time.

Now I want to switch to an Access (2010) database but my question is:
If I create the Access database with the same scheme as my SQLite database, do I have to change any of the SQL statements that I have written in my application? Or does this work interchangeable?

Also some side notes of why I am switching to an Access database instead of something like a SQL Server... Time does not allow this and costs neither.

Does anyone know what the impact will be if I'd simply replace the SQLite database with the Access database. And are there any differences in the SQL for these two for simple queries? I'm using things like 'INNER JOIN, IS NULL, SUM, COUNT'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Much is interchangeable, but some is not. Hence, the question "do I have to change any of the SQL statements that I have written in my application?" can only be answered after checking every single one of your SQL statements against the flavour of SQL supported by the target database engine.

Comment: Why access? SQL Server Express is free and having 100 concurrent users in Access will bring nothing but problems

Comment: Well as far as I see it, it is my only option. It's for commercial use and getting software like that installed on a server has a lot of procedural stuff involved, which will take a few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any differences in the SQL for these two for simple queries?

For the simplest of queries, not really. For example, the specific language features you mentioned (INNER JOIN, IS NULL, SUM, COUNT) will likely work without modification, with the possible exception that Access SQL often requires parentheses when a statement contains multiple JOINs (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21465226/2144390)).

> Does anyone know what the impact will be if I'd simply replace the SQLite database with the Access database.

That is impossible to predict without a complete code review. You will really just have to try it and see what (if anything) breaks.

Comment: Beware SQLite and Access implement even SUM and COUNT differently.  With [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html): *"In any aggregate function that takes a single argument, that argument can be preceded by the keyword DISTINCT."*  Access won't do that.