# INNER JOIN with multiple tables gives "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2013, oledbdataadapter

I am developing a VB.NET program which has the need to join multiple tables and display them on a DataGridView.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT m.idMedicos, m.Nombre, m.Apellido, h.idHistorial, h.CedulaP,
        r.*, rm.*,
        me.Nombre, me.Tipo, me.Administracion
   FROM Medicos m 
     INNER JOIN Historial h ON m.idMedicos = h.idMedicos 
     INNER JOIN Recetas r ON r.idHistorial = h.idHistorial 
     INNER JOIN RecetaMedica rm ON rm.idReceta = r.idReceta
     INNER JOIN Medicamentos me ON me.idMedicamento = rm.idMedicamento 
   WHERE h.CedulaP = $dato
```

(`$dato` varies with each query)

When I run my program, it fails with the error: "Syntax error in FROM clause".

I tried to add a comma before each `INNER`, but the error persists.

Note: I am using a  MS Access database, and I run all the queries with an OleDbDataAdapter.

```
Dim Consulta As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select m.idMedicos, m.Nombre, m.Apellido, 
             h.idHistorial, h.CedulaP, r.*, rm.*, me.Nombre, me.Tipo, me.Administracion 
             FROM Medicos m INNER JOIN Historial h ON m.idMedicos = h.idMedicos, INNER JOIN Recetas r ON r.idHistorial = h.idHistorial, INNER JOIN RecetaMedica rm ON rm.idReceta = r.idReceta,
             INNER JOIN Medicamentos me ON me.idMedicamento = rm.idMedicamento 
             WHERE h.CedulaP ='" + dato + "'", conexion)
```

¿Can you guys give me a hand and see what happens here ? :/

Comment: Your first query looks good to me. Can you run that in the DB directly and add the detailed error message here

Comment: Click this link: http://i.imgur.com/A9ePOAU.png

Comment: Execute the query directly in MySQL and not in your program code.

Comment: Does it work if you remove r.*, rm.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access syntax error in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465126/ms-access-syntax-error-in-from-clause)

Comment: Juergen d, im using Acces 2013..  :S

Comment: Why do you have commas (,) after each `INNER JOIN` on the second block of code? Try removing the comma at `ON m.idMedicos = h.idMedicos, INNER JOIN Recetas `

Comment: I remove these commas already Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution to this problem ( and indeed, long ago . )

I downloaded Fly Speed MySQL Query... It is a program in which you make your tables, relationships and others, that at the end , generates the correct code . (Sometimes you'll need to make some changes , if necessary ) .

http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you didn't include the me.idMedicamento in the initial SELECT so it's not recognizing it.

Comment: added what you said in the select ( and added another detail more ) and still not working ..   "Select m.idMedicos, m.Nombre, m.Apellido,h.idMedicos, h.idHistorial, h.CedulaP, r.*, rm.*, me.idMedicamento, me.Nombre, me.Tipo, me.Administracion FROM Medicos m INNER JOIN Historial h ON m.idMedicos = h.idMedicos INNER JOIN Recetas r ON r.idHistorial = h.idHistorial INNER JOIN RecetaMedica rm ON rm.idReceta = r.idReceta INNER JOIN Medicamentos me ON me.idMedicamento = rm.idMedicamento WHERE h.CedulaP ='"+dato+"'"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370416/2645091) answer it would seem that you require to use parentheses to keep the joins logically separated. 
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx) is a good read on the topic.

Your query should look like this when completed correctly:

```
Dim Consulta As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select m.idMedicos, m.Nombre, m.Apellido, h.idHistorial, h.CedulaP, r.*, rm.*, me.Nombre, me.Tipo, me.Administracion FROM (((Medicos m  INNER JOIN Historial h ON m.idMedicos = h.idMedicos )   INNER JOIN Recetas r ON r.idHistorial = h.idHistorial ) INNER JOIN RecetaMedica rm ON rm.idReceta = r.idReceta )    INNER JOIN Medicamentos me ON me.idMedicamento = rm.idMedicamento WHERE h.CedulaP ='" + dato + "'", conexion)
```